# Building a Route to output differences of two files

Tags: apache-camel

Trying to put together a file diff route... could someone help?  here is what I have ->

```
CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();
csv.setDelimiter(",");

from("file:inputdir?delete=true&sortBy=ignoreCase:file:name")
    .unmarshal(csv)
    .pollEnrich("file:backup?fileName=test.csv&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true")
    .unmarshal(csv)
    // Need to aggregate here!!!!
    .log("test");
```

A csv file gets dropped in the `/input` directory and then a backup file is consumed from the `/backup` directory.  I would like to compare these two files and output the difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a specific Camel problem. In order to solve this problem you may implement a diff functionality on your own, or you may use an existing library such as [java-diff-utils](https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/wiki/SampleUsage).

Pseudocode:

```
// read file 1 into a list "list1"
// read file 2 into a list "list2"
// use java-diff-utils to calculate the difference
Patch patch = DiffUtils.diff(list1, list2);
```